# Get all nodes with HTMLParser in java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I need to get all the elements of an HTML file, because I have to represent them on a tree. The problem is that I only can obtain the first node, the html node.

I am programming in Java with the HTMLParser Libraries.

My code is:

```
import org.htmlparser.Node;
import org.htmlparser.Parser;
import org.htmlparser.util.NodeList;
import org.htmlparser.util.ParserException;

class Principal
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Parser parser = new Parser("http://www.marca.com");
            NodeList list = parser.parse(null);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Node node = list.elementAt(i);
                System.out.println(node.getText());
            }
        } catch (ParserException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
}
```

I tryed with an iterator, but the result was the same.

The execution of the code produces the following result:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"


html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Does anyone know how I can get all the elements of the HTML file?

Comment: "To get at further content, the children of the top level nodes must be examined" http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/Parser.html

Comment: I tryed it too and the result is a nullPointerException in the sublist.size() line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying differents methods I solve the problem with a recursive call to iterate the different chilren of the tree.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

A Tree has different levels. On your approch you are just selecting the nodes in the top level. In order to print all nodes you need to go all the childnodes.

Comment: If I execute the node.getChildren() method and after y print the size of the result list I get a NullPointerException

Comment: DOCTYPE doens't have childElements but html does. try to catch the nullpointer exception and print instead `no child nodes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud using jsoup
Example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.marca.com").get();
Elements allNodes = doc.getAllElements()
```

You can reference here: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: I'm agree, but it is a requirement that I have to use the HTMLParser library